# How can I create an user controllable GUI for volume control like that of Seekbar (android) but in Libgdx?

Tags: seekbar

I am making a game in Libgdx. I searched for the way to implement Seekbar in the game but it is not in the libgdx (only in android). So, is there any way I can do it. I am trying to give a simple control over volume to the user so that they can change it anytime.